# Building a underworld

Tags: economy

My story is about a royal court that rules the underworld, the place between our world and heaven or hell. My question is, if it is a underworld where everyone is supposed to be dead, would there be typical jobs there? If everyone is already dead in the underworld can I eliminate farming and typical market places that sell produce.

Comment: This sounds primarily opinion based, which is not a question allowed here. But I'll ask you this, why do we farm? To feed ourselves. Do your spirits require nourishment?

Comment: The question is absolute average for this se, but you need to sell it better. Tell us more about that world. Why do you think people have jobs? What are the daily needs of your dead? Why isn't any other "job" than those 2 you mentioned an option?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE. Please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture. Please also read our meta posts about [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868) and [open-ended questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6654).The problems are this is too broad, not objective and [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437).  Please consider using our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183).

Answer (score 3):

The Greeks and Romans had myths about dead people who still desired food and drink, for example, [Tantalus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantalus):

> He was made to stand in a pool of water beneath a fruit tree with low branches, with the fruit ever eluding his grasp, and the water always receding before he could take a drink.

It's certainly possible to create an "after-world", so to speak, wherein people are no longer hungry or thirsty.  You can also create such an after-world where people are hungry and thirsty, but who cannot die from hunger or thirst.  Or you could create a type of "layered reality", where people can continually die from hunger or thirst and re-spawn or move on to the next reality, or reach a point where they cease to exist altogether (ie, dying on earth leads to the after-life, where dying there means a cessation of existence altogether).

What's important in thee worldbuilding process is identifying what the world is and how/what the characters are motivated by/for.  If death, for example, is no longer possible, then the desire for farming and markets would be to decrease the suffering of hunger and thirst, as hunger and thirst could turn into eternal angst if food and drink are not provided.  On the other hand, if there is no more need for food or drink in the afterlife, then what motivates them? Power? Greed? Influence? Sex? What are the desires and motivations of the characters/peoples/spirits/gods/etc?

Identifying the nature of the world and the rules therein will help you construct the so-called "royal court" to rule or govern the underworld.